From $\neg\exists\mathrm{v}\mathrm{S} $ derive $\forall\mathrm{v}\neg\mathrm{S}$ ' Introduction to logic - Patrick Suppes'
in Suppes's book 'Introdution to logic' He states that if $\mathrm{S}$ is any formula then from $\neg\exists\mathrm{v}\mathrm{S} $ we can derive $\forall\mathrm{v}\neg\mathrm{S}$.
I know how to prove it if $\mathrm{v}$ is not a subscript in $\mathrm{S}$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\{1\}&(1)\enspace\neg\exists\mathrm{v}\mathrm{S}&&P\\
\{2\}&(2)\enspace\mathrm{S}&&P\\
\{2\}&(3)\enspace\exists\mathrm{v}\mathrm{S}&2&ES\\
\Phi&(4)\enspace\mathrm{S}\rightarrow\exists\mathrm{v}\mathrm{S}&2,3&C.P.\\
\{1\}&(5)\enspace\neg\mathrm{S}&1,4&T\\
\{1\}&(6)\enspace\forall\mathrm{v}\neg\mathrm{S}&5&UG
\end{align*}
$$
But this doesn't work in the case where $\mathrm{v}$ is a subscript in $\mathrm{S}$, since step (3) will violate the restriction on E.S. I woder if there is a proof if v occurs as a subscript, for example let $\mathrm{S}$ be '$(Px{\alpha}_x)$' and let $\mathrm{v}$ be '$x$', I wonder if I am able to derive $\forall x\neg (Px{\alpha}_x)$ from $\neg\exists x (Px{\alpha}_x)$.
Here's the rules he use:
If S(v) is any formula in which the variable v is free, then S(t) is the formula which result from S(v) by substituting the term t for every free occurrence of c in S(v). Similarly, if S($v$) is an formula in which the ambiguous name $v$ occurs, then S(v) is obtained by substitution from S($v$) if and only if every occurrence of $v$ in S($v$) is replaced by the variable v.
\begin{align*}
&\text{abbreviation}&&\text{rule}&&\text{restriction}\\
&\text{P}&&\text{Introduction of premises}&&\text{None}\\
&\text{T}&&\text{Use of tautologies}&&\text{None}\\
&\text{C.P.}&&\text{Conditional proof}&&\text{None}\\
&\text{US}&&\text{From $\forall$vS derive S(t)}&&\text{No free occurrence of v within scope of quantifier using variable of t}\\
&\text{UG}&&\text{From S derive $\forall$vS}&&\text{(1) v not flagged}\\
&&&&&\text{(2) v not a subscript}\\
&\text{ES}&&\text{From $\exists$vS(v) derive S ($v$)}&&\text{Ambiguous name $v$ not previously used}\\
&\text{EG}&&\text{From S($v$) derive $\exists$vS(v)}&&\text{(1) v not a subscript}\\
&&&&&\text{(2) v not flagged}\\
&&&&&\text{(3) No occurrence of name $v$ within scope of quantifier using v}
\end{align*}
Flagging: A variable free in a premise is flagged and remains flagged in any line in which it is free and which depends on the premises.
Subscripts: When an ambiguous name is introduced by existential specification it must have as subscript all the free variables occurrence in the formula to which ES is applied.
And here's the definition of formulas:

A term is an expression which either names or describes some object, or results in a name or description of an object when the variables in the expression are replaced by names or descriptions.
An atomic formula is a predicate followed or flanked by the appropriate number of terms as arguments.

Every atomic formula is a formula.
If $\mathrm{S}$ is a formula, then $\neg(\mathrm{S})$ is a formula.
If $\mathrm{S}$ and $\mathrm{R}$ are formulas then $(\mathrm{S})\wedge(\mathrm{R}),(\mathrm{S})\vee(\mathrm{R}),(\mathrm{S})\rightarrow(\mathrm{R}),(\mathrm{S})\leftrightarrow(\mathrm{R})$ are formulas.
If $\mathrm{R}$ is a formula and $\mathrm{v}$ is any variable then $\forall\mathrm{v}(\mathrm{R})$ and $\exists\mathrm{v}(\mathrm{R})$ are formulas.
No expression is a formula unless its being so follows from the above rules.



Alphabet:
variables: $x,y,z,x_1,y_1,z_1,...$
names: $a,b,c,a_1,b_1,c_1,...$
ambiguous names: $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,{\alpha}_1,{\beta}_1,{\gamma}_1,...$
predicates: $A,B,C,A_1,B_1,C_1,...$

I'm not sure to understand the example... We have a "subscripted" variable when we introduce an "ambiguous name" $a$, i.e. a temporary constant used in specifications, and there is a free variables $x$ in previous assumptions. In this case, we write $a_x$ to keep track of the fact that the name in some sense in linked to the variable $x$.

Thus, the restriction in ES says: when deriving $\exists \mathrm{v} S(\mathrm{v})$ form $(v)$, take care that $\mathrm{v}$ is not a subscript. But in the proof above, the premises are $\lnot \exists \mathrm{v} S$ and $S$ and there are no further premises. And in case that $\mathrm{v}$ is subscript in $S$, we can simply choose a different variable $x$ (a new one) and prove $\lnot \exists x S \vdash \forall x \lnot S$.

Not easy to imagine a counterexample... Regarding $¬∃x(Pxα_x)$, it is not a formula: it occurs only temporary during a derivation. Thus, the issue is: how can it pop-up?

I thought that ¬∃x(Pxαx) is a formula, now I have no question.

Compare to the similar result at page 109.

Is $\alpha$ a term according to the book?

There are no formal syntactical specifications in the book; the Author introduces the term ambiguous names at page 81: "replace an existential quantifier by a 'temporary' constant; that is, some symbol is introduced as a name for the purposes immediately at hand."
